# Get a total of a Field / column Based on a field with String / text Value (PHP)

Tags: sql

I have this code. I want to get the total viewings (TotalViewings ) of each Quarter (Qtr). And my Qtr field has a text / string value. Group by is not working. I can't think of a way to do this. Please help.

```
SELECT Sum ( TotalViewings ) 
FROM Fenwicks_Stats_Figures 
Group By Qtr;
```

Comment: If `Qtr`s don't have the same data, it will not group, like `1st` and `first`. Please provide sample data and table structure

Comment: What do you mean with "not working". Do you get an error? If yes what is it? Do you get an unexpected result? If yes, please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Field? A table has _columns_.